# How can I pass an argument from a view to a form?

Tags: django

I am initializing a form with an argument. Part of my view:

```
items = Location.objects.filter(patient=pk)
query_form = QueryForm(items)
```

forms.py

```
class QueryForm(forms.Form, items):
    period = forms.IntegerField()
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all().order_by('location_name'))
```

but I get the error `NameError: name 'items' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override the `__init__` function of the form:

```
class QueryForm(forms.Form):
    period = forms.IntegerField()
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, items=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['location'].queryset = items.order_by('location_name')
```

then you can construct the form with:

```
items = Location.objects.filter(patient_id=pk)
query_form = QueryForm(items=items)
```